# is it possible to custom the image size of dangerouslySetInnerHTML in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` to render some article html in react, now I am facing a problem that the image from html source stream was out of the page width, is it possible to resize the image size in `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? or define the max width and height of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML`? this is my code :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';

import { ArticleDetailProps, connect, Dispatch, IArticleState, Loading } from 'umi';

const ArticleDetail: React.FC<ArticleDetailProps> = ({articles, dispatch, channelListLoading}) => {

  const location = useLocation();

  React.useEffect(()=>{
      dispatch({
        type: 'articles/getArticleDetail',
        payload: (location as any).query.id
      });
  },[]);

  let articleData = articles.article;
  return (
   <div>
      <h2>{articleData.title}</h2>
     <div style={{fontSize:'15px'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: articleData.content}} />
   </div>
  );
};


const mapStateToProps = ({articles, loading}: {articles: IArticleState, loading: Loading}) => {
   return {
      articles,
      userListLoading: loading.models.articles
  }
}
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
  return {
      dispatch
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ArticleDetail);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give your article wrapper a class:

```
<div className="article" style={{fontSize:'15px'}} dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: articleData.content}} />
```

And style its images accordingly:

```css
.article img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```